# Codeigniter - Can't update data in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have some problem with CodeIgniter, I can't update data in a record in CodeIgniter. 'id_user' is the primary key of my user table. I have tried to solve this problem but I couldn't. I hope someone can help with this problem. Thanks a lot :)

I have posted the code below :

HTML5 code :

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(). 'crud/update'; ?>" method="post">
    <input name="id_user" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $id_usernya ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Alamat :</label>
        <textarea name="alamat_user" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Alamat" ><?php echo $usernya->alamat_user ?></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="kodepos_user" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $usernya->kodepos_user ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="provinsi_user">
        <select name="provinsi_id_user" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Pilih Provinsi</option>
            <option selected value="<?php echo $usernya->provinsi_user ?>"><?php echo $usernya->provinsi_user ?></option>
            <?php echo $provinsi ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="kota_user">
        <select name="kota_id_user" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Pilih Kota</option>
            <option selected value="<?php echo $usernya->kota_user ?>"><?php echo $usernya->kota_user ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Simpan">
</form>
```

Controller :

```
class Crud extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();      
    $this->load->model('m_data');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}

function edit($id_user){
        $where = array('id_user' => $id_user);
        $data['user'] = $this->m_data->edit_data($where,'user')->result();
        $this->load->view('back/user/v_beranda',$data);
        redirect('beranda/index');
    }

    function update(){
    $id_user = $this->input->post('id_user');
    $alamat_user = $this->input->post('alamat_user');
    $kodepos_user = $this->input->post('kodepos_user');
    $provinsi_id_user = $this->input->post('provinsi_id_user');
    $kota_id_user = $this->input->post('kota_id_user');

    $data = array(
        'alamat_user' => $alamat_user,
        'kodepos_user' => $kodepos_user,
        'provinsi_id_user' => $provinsi_id_user,
        'kota_id_user' => $kota_id_user
    );

    $where = array(
        'id_user' => $id_user
    );

    $this->m_data->update_data($where,$data,'user');
    redirect('beranda/index');
}
```

Model code :

```
<?php 

class M_data extends CI_Model{

    function edit_data($where,$table){      
        return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
    }

    function update_data($where,$data,$table){
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->update($table,$data);
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you got? At least, a better explanation on why you say it fails.

Comment: I can't update a data record

Comment: Yes, I know. What I mean is, what happens with the current code? Does it shows an error? Or it just shows success but with no data edited.

Comment: it's just shows success but with no data edited

Comment: `$this->M_data->update_data($where,$data,'user');` model needs to be called uppercase!

Comment: check the data in your model try insert it manually in your dbms check if it has an error

Comment: please mention which model function not work and what is the error that you got?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your Model like what your have done on your Controller

```
class M_data extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function edit_data($where,$table){      
        return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
    }

    function update_data($where,$data,$table){
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->update($table,$data);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to print query to check what exact query getting executed

```
$this->db->last_query():
```

and which error its shows when you execute above query